# PHP binary manipulation

Tags: php, binary, unpack

Okay, so I am having a bit of trouble (likely due to my ignorance) figuring this out.

```
$binary = base64_decode("AAAAAgYA3ncsRjy9");
```

So, what I have here are 12 bytes of binary data, yes?

I need to turn this into:

```
$binary = array("0"=>"00000000", "1"=>"00000000", "2"=>"00000000", "3"=>"00000010", "4"=>"00000110", "5"=>"00000000", "6"=>"11011110", "7"=>"01110111, "8"=>"00101100", "9"=>"01000110", "10"=>"00111100", "11"=>"10111101");
```

And, ultimately, drop the first 6 bytes, and split the rest into 2 byte pairs.

```
$binary = array("0"=>"1101111001110111", "1"=>"0010110001000110", "2"=>"0011110010111101"
```

Then, convert those 2 bytes chunks into base 10 decimal.

```
$binary = array("0"=>"56951", "1"=>"11334", "2"=>"15549");
```

The reason I have chose to include the actual data is because I want to make sure I am using the correct terminology.  I have been trying to work with pack/unpack and have simply not been able to get this done, likely due to my not understanding the different available choices for the format argument.

I am certain I have been extremely confusing in my explanation, please accept my apologies.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

For posterity:

[PHP Manual - function.pack](http://www.php.net/function.pack)

[PHP Manual - function.unpack](http://www.php.net/function.unpack)

[PHP Manual - function.call-user-func-array](http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$binary = base64_decode("AAAAAgYA3ncsRjy9");
$binary = substr($binary, 6);
var_dump(unpack("n*", $binary));
```

`n` is unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order). With `*` this format is used for the entire remaining data.

Comment: Wish i could give +100 for this answer !

Comment: Absolutely wonderfully simple.  A question if I may: if the binary data is simply treated as a string and thus substr is an available function why does it print/echo out as "Þw,F<½"?

Comment: @SamanthaP `base64_decode` returns a string and the ‘text’ you see is the characters the data corresponds to.

Comment: @Gumbo Well, thank you immensely for the prompt and very helpful answer.  *Toast

Comment: Okay... :(  `$bin != pack("n*",unpack("n*",$bin))`, but `I==confused`. Trying to package it back up now after I've done my magic :(

Comment: @SamanthaP `pack` expects the values as separate arguments. You can use `call_user_func_array` to call a function with arguments given in an array: `$bin === call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("n*"), unpack("n*", $bin)))`

Comment: @Gumbo Wonderful, Immaculate, Greatly Appreciated.  Should have examined the manual better.